# Plotting data from 3D array across axis 0, side by side according to axis 1 and 2

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

So here is what I have: `n` is a 3D array, where:

```
x = [[a,b],
     [c,d]]
```

represents each element in the row.

If I wanted to graph `a` across all of x, I would say:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
graph_data = n[:,0,0]
plt.plot(graph_data)
```

What I would like to do is create a plot like this:

graph(a) | graph(b)

------------ + ------------

graph(c) | graph(d)

---

Online, I see all kinds of pictures of plots like:

[image]

Which uses seaborn's wrapper around pyplot.

There must be some way for me to put my plots of the elements of x such that it looks like (in essence):

```
x = [[plot,plot],
     [plot,plot]]
```

---

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This gave me some trouble...and, unless I'd seen examples, I never would have known it was possible, so I'll leave this up.  Anyhow, in order to do what I am asking about, the following code is an easy start:

```
zarray = np.zeros((10,2,2))
zarray[:,0,0] = 0
zarray[:,0,1] = 1
zarray[:,1,0] = 2
zarray[:,1,1] = 3

def plot_yz_over_x_elementwise(zarray):
    for i in range(zarray.shape[1]):
        for j in range(zarray.shape[2]):
            plt.subplot2grid((zarray.shape[1],zarray.shape[2]),(i,j))
            plt.plot(zarray[:,i,j])
plot_yz_over_x_elementwise(zarray)
```

[image]

Comment: 1 year later, more understanding of matplotlib: flat out, bar none easiest way to do a subplot grid.